# Display data from array in table view on first view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xml, xcode

I'm attempting to parse some XML data into an array, then display the array in a Table View on the First View Controller. You can see that I already have parsed the data into what I need, then it's all set up in the array. I just can't figure out how to get it to send to the table view within the GUI. Here is my array:

```
    NSString* mountPoint1 = [mountArray objectAtIndex: 11];
    NSString* mountPoint2 = [mountArray objectAtIndex: 17];
    NSString* mountPoint3 = [mountArray objectAtIndex: 23];
    NSString* mountPoint4 = [mountArray objectAtIndex: 29];
    NSString* currentSong1 = [mountArray objectAtIndex: 16];
    NSString* currentSong2 = [mountArray objectAtIndex: 22];
    NSString* currentSong3 = [mountArray objectAtIndex: 28];
    NSString* currentSong4 = [mountArray objectAtIndex: 34];
    NSString* listeners1 = [mountArray objectAtIndex: 14];
    NSString* listeners2 = [mountArray objectAtIndex: 20];
    NSString* listeners3 = [mountArray objectAtIndex: 26];
    NSString* listeners4 = [mountArray objectAtIndex: 32];
    NSLog(@"mountpoint1 should be dev = %@", mountPoint1);
    NSLog(@"All data = %@", mountArray);
    // First mount is 11
    NSLog(@"First mount point = %@", mountPoint1);
    NSLog(@"Currrent Song playing on mount Dev = %@", currentSong1);
    NSLog(@"Currrent listeners on mount Dev = %@", listeners1);
    NSLog(@"Second mount point = %@", mountPoint2);
    NSLog(@"Currrent Song playing on mount Metal = %@", currentSong2);
    NSLog(@"Currrent listeners on mount Metal = %@", listeners2);
    NSLog(@"Third mount point = %@", mountPoint3);
    NSLog(@"Currrent Song playing on mount OrienLive = %@", currentSong3);
    NSLog(@"Currrent listeners on mount OrienLive = %@", listeners3);
    NSLog(@"Fourth mount point = %@", mountPoint4);
    NSLog(@"Currrent Song playing on mount Rock = %@", currentSong4);
    NSLog(@"Currrent listeners on mount Rock = %@", listeners4);
```

Comment: Now go refactor your code using a for loop and come back after that.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Not sure what I would need a for loop for if i already have the array set up. Please advise

Comment: @xxxxxx that bunch of calls to `objectAtIndex:` is code duplication and is not good for readability.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas on how i should do it then? This is the only way that seems to be working for me...

Comment: @xxx if you need multiple values associated with an object, and you really can't refactor your code, you better use an NSDictionary - for a key-value store, it's more acceptable to have a lot of calls to the same method. It's just conceptually better.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do exactly? You can just do something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //.. after initial setup
    NSInteger position = indexPath.row * 6;
    cell.mountLabel.text = [self.mountArray objectAtIndex:position + 11];
    cell.songLabel.text = [self.mountArray objectAtIndex:position + 16];
    cell.listenerLabel.text = [self.mountArray objectAtIndex:position + 14];
    //.. continue with other setup
}
```

Something like that?

Comment: I am just trying to take the current song, mountpoint, and listeners from my internet radio and display it in some sort of fashion within the GUI, it doesn't necessarily have to be a table view either. Im just having a hard time understanding how to display the array in the GUI. Please advise

Comment: Well if you want to display an array, then the most natural choice is a tableview. You have more than 1 song don't you.

Comment: There is a total of four streams on my site, which all need to be displayed somehow.

Comment: You need to decide your UI yourself. That's a design decision. You can either list them in a table (which may look radically different from each other), or do something like the Weather app, or just use plain, static labels.

Comment: Well the UI can always be altered when I can figure how its done. I just need an easy example of how to display something from the array in the table view to give me an idea of how it's done to get me going. I appreciate your support, please advise.

Comment: isn't my answer just that? Displaying your array in a tableview? Please let me know what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: Okay well with the code you have provided, where exactly that be placed? Right after the array? I seem to be getting errors wherever i place it.

Comment: If you want to use a table, you need to use a `UITableViewController` or implement all required methods for `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`. If you don't know how to set up a table then you have a long way to go. Read, for example, this: http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-and.html